# Laravel Sanctum: send cookies to any domain/host

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to integrate a Laravel application into a larger application and running into an issue with session persistence.

The Laravel application should serve single-page applications running on any domain name.

I'm just getting my cherry popped with Laravel so I have no clue how to get rid of this feature.

```
// config/sanctum.php
// ...
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1') ),
// ...
```

I have tried adding * but no luck. I don't want to try adding the referrer domain since not all browsers pass it. The application is behind a reverse proxy so $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] won't work.

How do you configure Laravel Sanctum to send session cookies for any domain name without having to add each domain name in the SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS .env file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some 491 different google searches I was able to fix this by adding `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to the top `$middleware` array within `app/Http/Kernel.php` to ensure all requests are stateful including api requests.

It will work if the CORS policy allows all/any domain names.